# Cannot add new environment to Anaconda Navigator

Tags: anaconda

I have been using Anaconda for a while now (I have been dealing only with the Navigator GUI). I have been using it mostly at home or on a private notebook.
I changed job and now moved to a new company. They are not aware what is Anaconda so I am quite left on my own now.
I have benn installed Anaconda3 on my desktop computer in a company environment and I already encountered two problems.

1. Anaconda Navigator loads for ages. Really it is around 10 minutes till it loads. Is there any way to speed it up somehow? On my home computer it does not take more than 1 minute.
2. I cannot add, create new environment in the Anaconda Navigator. It seems that the System tries to create the new environment but after a while of processing the new environment tab suddenly disappears like nothing happend, and I am left with the base environment.

I checked the log and this is the log message I get:

````
```json
[
    {
        "level": "ERROR",
        "line": 587,
        "message": "HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.anaconda.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000203BDDC1BE0>, 'Connection to api.anaconda.org timed out. (connect timeout=6)'))",
        "method": "_get_api_info",
        "module": "client_api",
        "path": "C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/lib/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/api/client_api.py",
        "time": "2018-07-12 18:16:55,181"
    }
]
```
````

The OS System the company is using is Windows 10.

Thank you for your help in advance! I need desperately some guidance how to proceed further as the IT department is clueless.
Thank you again in advance, any help is appriciated!

Comment: Can you access https://api.anaconda.org/ from a browser? It's possible that your company has filtering or network restrictions that are blocking your ability to access the api.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Will check it tomorrow and get back.

Comment: Hi. Yes, I can access api.anaconda.org. It shows a json format file:
{
  "api_docs_url": "https://api.anaconda.org/docs", 
  "brand": "Anaconda Cloud", 
  "conda_url": "https://conda.anaconda.org/", 
  "main_url": "https://anaconda.org/", 
  "ok": 1, 
  "pypi_url": "https://pypi.anaconda.org/", 
  "swagger_url": "https://api.anaconda.org/swagger.json"
}

Comment: So what am I supposed to do, as the problem still persists...:(